# ng-dynamic-forms: json model, render 3 controls on inline row

Tags: angular, forms, dynamic, ng-bootstrap

Versions:

Angular 5.2.1

@ng-dynamic-forms: 5.4.2

@ng-dynamic-forms/ui-bootstrap: 5.4.2

Nothing fancy here ...

Using the following JSON model, I am attempting to render the first 3 controls of a form, those in the 'group', on the same bootstrap row.

Currently, the 3 controls are rendered on separate rows. The layout.grid.container = "row" object not working but I cannot figure out how to essentially add the bootstrap "row" class to a div that encompasses the first 3 controls.

Any advice or insights are greatly appreciated.
TIA, Eric.

```
  jsonForm = `
[
  {
    "type": "GROUP",
    "id": "full_name",
    "layout": {
      "grid": {
        "container": "row"
      }
    },
    "group": [
      {
        "type": "INPUT",
        "id": "first_name",
        "label": "First Name",
        "maxLength": 20,
        "placeholder": "First Name",
        "layout": {
          "element": {
            "label": "First Name"
          },
          "grid": {
            "label": "col-sm-4",
            "control": "col-sm-4"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "INPUT",
        "id": "middle_initial",
        "label": "Middle Initial",
        "maxLength": 1,
        "placeholder": "Middle Initial",
        "layout": {
          "element": {
            "label": "First Name"
          },
          "grid": {
            "label": "col-sm-4",
            "control": "col-sm-4"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "INPUT",
        "id": "last_name",
        "label": "Last Name",
        "maxLength": 20,
        "placeholder": "Last Name",
        "layout": {
          "element": {
            "label": "First Name"
          },
          "grid": {
            "label": "col-sm-4",
            "control": "col-sm-4"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "INPUT",
    "id": "ssn",
    "label": "SSN",
    "maxLength": 20,
    "placeholder": "###-##-####",
    "mask": ["/[0-9]/","/[0-9]/","/[0-9]/","-","/[0-9]/","/[0-9]/","-","/[0-9]/","/[0-9]/","/[0-9]/","/[0-9]/"],
    "validators": {
      "required": null
    },
    "errorMessages": {
      "required": "Field {{id}} is required"
    }
  }
]`;
```

Form code:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <dynamic-bootstrap-form [group]="formGroup" [model]="formModel"></dynamic-bootstrap-form>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, forgot this question was still unanswered.

What I ended up doing was switching to the ngx-formly package(s) and development was straightforward from there.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `ng-bootstrap` plugin instead of `ui-bootstrap`.  `ui-bootstrap` is putting grouped elements under `fieldset` instead of `div` so the problem is created